# Compare 2 tables in MS Access without duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Here is the short of it: I want to compare two tables.

- From Left table, I want all records.
- From the Right table, I want distinct records returned when the joined fields match.
- If the Left table has 3 records, and  Right table has 1, I want the query to return blanks for Right table rows 2 & 3.

What is happening is for Left table’s 3 records, Right table is matching the same record for all 3 rows. I have tried using `Select Distinct` and `Select DistinctRow` but problem persist. I have also tried every combo I could think of for grouping. It seems like this should be super easy but it’s not.

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SD13_PYMTS.[PYMT Date], SD13_PYMTS.Last, SD13_PYMTS.First,
                SD13_PYMTS.[PERS ID], SD13_PYMTS.[Payment No], SD13_PYMTS.Gross, 
                SD13_PYMTS.FWH, SD13_PYMTS.SWH, SD13_PYMTS.Net, SD762_TAXDTL.ID, 
                SD762_TAXDTL.[Recipient Name], SD762_TAXDTL.Net
FROM SD13_PYMTS 
LEFT JOIN SD762_TAXDTL 
      ON (SD13_PYMTS.[PERS ID] = SD762_TAXDTL.[Recipient PERS ID]) 
     AND (SD13_PYMTS.Net = SD762_TAXDTL.Net)
ORDER BY SD13_PYMTS.Net;
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired result? No need for dozen columns, but simplified problem.

Comment: If Right table is returning repeat matches, it sounds like the join fields are not uniquely pairing with Left table records. So you may need to add another identifier. Please post few rows from either table so we can help.

Comment: Have you tried a subquery?

Comment: PYMT Date Last PERS ID Payment No Gross FWH SWH Net ID
3/10/2017 SEAVER 16 CK27527663 $1,358.97  $129.74  $86.75  $884.68  180007
PYMT Date Last PERS ID Payment No Gross FWH SWH Net ID
3/10/2017 SEAVER 16 CK27527664 $1,358.97  $129.74  $86.75  $884.68  180007